# Reducing object array with fallback values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Consider the following object:

```
var content = [
    {
        id: 'tab1',
        langCode: 'en',
        title: 'rocket'
    },
    {
        id: 'tab1',
        langCode: 'da',
        title: 'raket'
    },
    {
        id: 'tab2',
        langCode: 'en',
        title: 'factory'        
    },
    {
        id: 'tab3',
        langCode: 'es',
        title: 'boligrafo'
    },      
];
```

I'd like to reduce this array, to a new array with the following restriction:

- No duplicate IDs
- Values from the local language should take preference
- In case there are no local translation, fall back to English
- All other translations should be discarded (even if they have a unique ID)

That means, the output from the data above would be as follows, if the local language were Danish:

```
[
    {
        id: 'tab1',
        langCode: 'da',
        title: 'raket'
    },
    {
        id: 'tab2',
        langCode: 'en',
        title: 'factory'        
    },
];
```

My goal is to keep the code as short and readable as possible, and I have ES6 and Lodash at my full disposal. This is what I have so far:

```
const LOCAL_LANG = 'da'; // Hard coded for the sake of the example

let localArr = content.filter(item => item.langCode === LOCAL_LANG);

if(LOCAL_LANG !== 'en') {
    let enArr = content.filter(item => item.langCode === 'en');
    for (let i = 0; i < enArr.length; i++) {
        if (!_.find(localArr, { 'id': enArr[i].id})) {
            localArr.push(enArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This does the trick, but it creates two duplicate arrays, and then merges them back together in what I feel is a clumpsy way. I would like to see a more elegant solution – preferably one, where I don't have to pass over the arrays so many times.

An alternative (and perhaps slightly cleaner) solution would be to reduce the array on `langCode === 'da' || langCode === 'en'` on first pass, and then remove duplicates ... but still I'm just feeling I'm missing the most obvious solution.

Thanks!

Comment: *Values from the local language should take preference* how do you know that?

Comment: I presume english is the fallback but for the rest how do we know which one is the local language.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have the local language stored in a variable. I will add it to my example.

Comment: maybe you add some more data to reflect more your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reduce everything into an object keyed by ID to enable easy lookups without those extra `_.find` calls:

```
const targetLang = 'da';
const fallbackLang = 'en';

const itemsByKey = content.reduce((allItems, item) => {
  if (item.langCode === targetLang 
      || (!(item.id in allItems) && item.langCode === fallbackLang)) 
  {
    return Object.assign(allItems, { [item.id]: item });
  } else {
    return allItems;
  }
}, {});
```

This solution will require only one pass over the original array. If you then need this lookup object converted back into an array, you'd need a second pass:

```
var normalizedArray = Object.keys(itemsByKey).map(key => itemsByKey[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tree and filter the wanted items.

```js
var content = [{ id: 'tab1', langCode: 'en', title: 'rocket' }, { id: 'tab1', langCode: 'da', title: 'raket' }, { id: 'tab2', langCode: 'es', title: 'boligrafo' }, { id: 'tab2', langCode: 'en', title: 'pen' }],
    object = Object.create(null);

content.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a.id] = object[a.id] || {}
    object[a.id][a.langCode] = a;
});  

var result = Object.keys(object).map(k => object[k][Object.keys(object[k]).filter(l => l !== 'en')[0] || 'en']);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows.

```js
var content = [
    {
        id: 'tab1',
        langCode: 'en',
        title: 'rocket'
    },
    {
        id: 'tab1',
        langCode: 'da',
        title: 'raket'
    },
    {
        id: 'tab2',
        langCode: 'es',
        title: 'boligrafo'
    },
    {
        id: 'tab2',
        langCode: 'en',
        title: 'pen'
    }
],
result = content.sort((a,b) => a.langCode === "en" ? 1 : -1)
                .reduce((p,c) => p.findIndex(o => o.id === c.id) === -1  ? p.concat(c) : p,[]);
console.log(result);
```